# Push notification architecture for very high volume

Tags: apple-push-notifications

Is Apple push notification architecture setup for sending very high volume (dozens of notifications per hour) ?
Is this allowed by Apple ? What are the constraints/limits ? Is it reliable ? Are there some delays ? Is there a price to pay for using their service ?

Comment: I wouldn't consider dozens of notifications an hour "very high volume"

Comment: @Jimmy: Unless it's per user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order:

1. Yes.
2. Yes.
3. I'm not sure.
4. Mostly; delivery of notifications isn't guaranteed, but the service will attempt to deliver the latest notification your app's generated when a device reappears on the network after being unavailable.
5. Again, there are no particular guarantees, but if the target device is on a good 3G or wifi connection then you can expect the notifications to be delivered within a few seconds of being sent.
6. No. You do, however, need to run your own push notification server (or use a third-party notification-delivery service), which may get costly if you're using a lot of bandwidth and CPU time for your notifications.

For more information, check out the [Apple Push Notification Service](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/prerelease/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW9) section in the developer docs.

Answer (score 2):

You should read the [Local and Push Notification Programming Guide, chapter Apple Push Notification Service](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW9).